# Bit banging TFT RGB

Tags: lcd, dot-matrix-display

I am replacing an EOL 240x320 TFT LCD in a existing hardware product, where the recommended replacement does not support the system 8080 MPU interface (Driver ST7789 supports it but it is not implemented in the interface selection for the display).

The old one was bit-bang software controlled through an 16 bit 8080 MPU interface (driver was HX8347-D), with a microcontroller without a RGB hardware peripheral. The main reason for not simply selecting a display with the same interface is a mechanical one.

Now i ask, is it reasonable at all to attempt to bit-bang a 240x320 TFT display via 16 bit RGB interface on a 48Mhz MCU, where the dot clock can not be run perfectly? The update rate of the displayed images of the display is quite low, so i am mainly concerned about the dot clock having pauses in time.

Comment: AFAIK synchronous RGB LCD relies on the pixel clock to refresh the display, so the display refresh rate is always tied to the pixel data rate. With a slow MCU, you do need a 8080/6800 type LCD that can self-refresh regardless of input data rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial Analog LCD pixel video is synchronous so the dot clock of the generator is assumed to be stable and synchronous with Hsync and Vsync

I presume it is something like this , https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/OriseTech/OTM3225C/